# Why isn't plural ihr used for Formal instead of Sie?

Tags: grammar, etymology, pronoun, formality, personal-pronoun

In most of the Indo-European languages that I know of, The [T-V distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%E2%80%93V_distinction) applies, that the second plural form (referring to many people, **vous**, **Bы**, and **you** in English) is used in the singular as a formal way of addressing another person. In German however, we use the third person plural for constructing formal sentences (**sie-Sie**.) How can this be explained and in what other languages can this be seen?

I can think of the possibility that formal **Er** (as described here: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform#Pronomen) might have had an influence. I can imagine that when addressing a woman, a formal **Sie** could have been used. But this doesn't explain the verb conjugation.

The most useful information I could gather on the subject so far was that "**Ihr**" was indeed used to formally address a person, but was replaced by "**Sie**" in about 19th, 20th century, no clue why. Also, the Dative form of "**Ihnen**" and the Possessive form "**Ihr**" still derive from the old pronoun.

Comment: Als Randnotiz: Weder für Polnisch noch Italienisch.

Comment: In Portuguese, at least in the European variant, one formally speaks in the third person singular to someone. If one where to ask: "Are you looking for something?", that could be translated to "O senhor procura alguma coisa?", i.e. literally "Is the (gentle)man looking for something?", or when speaking to a woman, "A senhora procura alguma coisa?".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Interesting site here on courtesy in 18th century German.

[18. Jahrhundert Anreden](http://www.marquise.de/de/1700/buerger/anrede.shtml)

Of special interest to you perhaps:

> **Plural und Indirektion**
>
> Eine Plural-Anrede gilt als höflicher als eine Singular-Anrede. Daher
> ist "Ihr" höflicher als "Du". Noch höflicher ist es, jemanden nicht
> direkt anzusprechen. In asiatischen Kulturen wird das noch heute sehr
> deutlich: Egal, ob es um die direkte Anrede oder um direkten
> Augenkontakt geht, beide stellen eine Durchbrechung der
> Individualdistanz und mithin einen Einbruch in die persönliche Sphäre
> dar. Im Japanischen z.B. sagt man, wenn man besonders höflich sein
> will, nicht "Du gehst" sondern man benutzt die Passivform, "Du wirst
> gegangen". Das erscheint einem Deutsch-Muttersprachler in der
> Übersetzung seltsam, aber der wichtige Aspekt ist: Das Passiv wirkt
> nicht direkt auf den Gesprächspartner, sondern macht einen Umweg, und
> darin besteht die Höflichkeit. Ein ähnliches Prinzip wirkt im
> Deutschen, nur daß uns das heute nicht mehr so klar ist: Jemanden in
> der 3. Person anzusprechen bedeutet eigentlich, ihn eben nicht
> anzusprechen, sondern quasi mit einer imaginären anderen Person über
> ihn zu sprechen. Mithin ist "Geht es Ihm gut?" höflicher als "Geht es
> Euch gut?". Daraus ergibt sich folgende Hierarchie der
> Höflichkeitsstufen:
>
> 2. Pers. sg. (Du) -> 2. Pers. pl. (Ihr) -> 3. Pers. sg. (Sie/Er) -> 3. Pers. pl. (Sie)
>
> Wer extrem höflich sein will, z.B. einem Fürsten gegenüber, spricht
> den Anderen nicht einmal in der dritten Person an, sondern baut eine
> weitere Stufe der Indirektion ein. In diesem Fall kommen Worte wie
> "dero" oder "derselbe" ins Spiel, die eine besondere, noch indirektere
> Form der dritten Person darstellen: "Darf ich bei Dero Gnaden um
> Audienz ersuchen?"

Translation

> A plural form of address is considered more polite than the singular
> form. That's why "Ihr" is more polite than "Du". It's even more polite
> to not address someone directly at all. In Asian cultures that is
> still pronounced to this day: No matter whether it's a matter of
> direct address or of edye contact, both constitute a breech of
> distance between individuals and thus a breech of personal space. In
> Japanese, for example, when trying to be polite, you don't say "you
> go/are going". Instead you use the passive form, essentially "you will
> be went". This sounds strange to a German [or English] native speaker,
> but the point is: the passive form does not act directly upon the
> other side of the conversation. Rather, it detours, and that is what
> makes is polite. There is a similar principle in German, though we
> aren't even aware of it nowadays: To address somebody in the third
> person means that you are specifically not addressing them directly,
> but rather speaking to an imaginary third person about them. As a
> result, "Geht es Ihm gut?" [How is he?] is more polite than "Geht es
> Euch gut?" [How are you? (*)]. This results in the following hierarchy
> of courtesy levels:
>
> 2. pers. sing. (Du) -> 2. pers. pl. (Ihr) -> 3. pers. sg. (Sie/Er) -> 3. pers. pl (Sie)
>
> Some who wants to be *extremely* polite, e.g. when addressing a lord,
> won't even use the third person form, but use another level of
> indirection. In this case, words like "dero" or "derselbe" enter the
> picture, which form a special, even more indirect form of third person
> address: "Darf ich bei Dero Gnaden um Audienz ersuchen?" [May I
> beseech His Eminenz for an audience?]

One other note: the 2. pers. pl. form of address isn't unheard of in some areas with their own dialects. Years ago, I worked in Coburg in Upper Franconia and was taken aback/amused when they asked me a local *Gasthaus* "Wollt Ihr ein Bier?" and "Was wollt Ihr denn essen?"

Comment: I would vote for an English translation of this German text-piece.

Comment: On your last note: That ("Ihr") would typically be used to evade the decision on whether to address someone as "Sie" or "Du" and sometimes is an indirect hint to tell them.

Comment: @tofro in that form I know it from upper and lower Bavarian, but in upper Franconian it seemed to be the formal form of address - even among people who knew each other but were still using formal address with each other. It's been quite a while, though.

Comment: Very well explained! I like that germans always try to be polite. The answer has something to do with addressing with "Er/Sie" as I guessed.

Comment: Yes, essentially, as the transition shows, third person (er/sie) is even **more** polite than _ihr_, so it became established.